# In data set, I want to change each element to p value

Tags: r, p-value, standardized

```
 c<- c(1.88, 2.33, -2.4, -0.6)
 dim(c)<-c(2,2)
```

I have a data set, 9X12 matrix.
The data set is standardized to be normal, so I can compare each element.

For better comparing, I want to change each value to p-value.

How can I make it? (Please use above matrix.)

Please let me know.

Comment: This is highly unspecific. Please add some information on how do you want to calculate the p-values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `c` for a variable name (you know better):

```
A <- c(1.88, 2.33, -2.4, -0.6)
dim(A) <- c(2,2)
```

You are looking for `pnorm`:

```
pnorm(A)
#           [,1]        [,2]
# [1,] 0.9699460 0.008197536
# [2,] 0.9900969 0.274253118
```